# How can I set the vertical/horizontal height of a JLabel? (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, jlabel

When I click a `JButton`, I want a new `Jlabel` to be created and to appear on a position on the GUI of my choice. Note that I am using the GUI builder in Netbeans, meaning it auto-generates the code for GUI components.

I tried seeing what the auto-generated code does when creating a label but it didn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: From the comments: "Am creating a weekly planner program, so if the user says "5pm - 7pm", a block (colored jLabel) 2 units long will be created and display, if the user wants "7pm - 8pm" a block (colored jLabel) 1 unit long will be created" add essential information to the question. [mcve] would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving us any code the thing that should have more chance to work for you is the following:

Add the label from the builder with the regular way. Exactly as you added the other components. Switch to code and you will see somewhere like

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("some text");
```

Just right below this line make the label invisible (after it is being declared).

```
label.setVisible(false);
```

Now the label is there, in the position you want it. Now the only that is left is to show it - make it visible when the button is pressed. So...

```
button.addActionListener(e -> label.setVisible(true));
```

Comment: Is there any way to create the jLabel after clicking on the jbutton? Am creating a weekly planner program, so if the user says "5pm - 7pm", a block (colored jLabel) 2 units long will be created and display, if the user wants "7pm - 8pm" a block (colored jLabel) 1 unit long will be created.

Comment: Creating the label invisible and on click making it visible is the same thing with creating it on click. In both situations user does not its existense. On click make it visible and change its text will work. Or give us code to help you more.

Comment: I like that approach a lot, the only problem now is some blocks will be vertically taller then others and that is determined by the user. Can I change the vertical size of a jlabel while the program is running?

Answer (score 0):

Graphically it should be appearing like this, then you can modify the label with the mouse, keep in mind if you want you can change font and size of font, it helps to increase the size of label as well

[image]